# Google Groups - Send Notifications to Another Email Address

Tags: google-groups

I have joined a Google group using the Google account associated with my gmail address. I would like notifications from the group to go to another email address. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to edit your personal settings: Either in membership and email setting or in global settings
[image]